# How to properly extend lspconfig server list from another file

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I've been using [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim) and tweaked my setup to turn a single-file config into a bunch of modular files. Now, I've got separate files for lsp with only `lua_ls` server, and each programming language has its own file, covering `treesitter`, `mason`, and conform configs. The only issue is I'm struggling to expand the servers for `lspconfig` but can't make it to work. This is my `lsp.lua` file.

```
{
  'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
  branch = 'master',
  event = { 'BufReadPost', 'BufNewFile', 'BufWritePre' },
  dependencies = {
    'williamboman/mason.nvim',
    'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
    { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim', opts = {} },
  },
  opts = {},
  config = function()
    local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
    capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities(capabilities)

    -- This function gets run when an LSP connects to a particular buffer.
    local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
      -- bunch of kepmaps here
    end

    local servers = {
      lua_ls = {
        Lua = {
          workspace = { checkThirdParty = false },
          telemetry = { enable = false },
          diagnostics = {
            globals = { 'vim' },
          },
        },
      },
    }

    require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
      ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers),
      handlers = {
        function(server_name)
          require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup({
            capabilities = capabilities,
            on_attach = on_attach,
            settings = servers[server_name],
            filetypes = (servers[server_name] or {}).filetypes,
          })
        end,
      },
    })
  end,
},
```

This is my go.lua file

```
-- mason and treesitter stuff here
{
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = function(_, opts)
      vim.tbl_keys(opts.ensure_installed, { 'gopls' })
    end,
},
```

And it gives me this error Expected table, got nil. What am I doing wrong here?